# Receiving Values from javascript setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML canvas to model a differential equation via the Euler Forward method. I am using the javascript setinterval to call the function as my code is as follows

```
<script>
function step(theta,v) {
    //calculate values of theta and v
    //output result
    return theta,v;
}

setInterval(step,0.001); 
</script>
```

however I want the function to output v and theta so I can feed them back into the function for the second iteration and then again for the third iteration and so one. So how can a periodical call the function and receive the output of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking for something like the following:

```
let currentParams ={v: 1, theta: 5};

function step(v, theta) {
   return {v: v + theta, theta: v-theta }; // just an example of operation that should be done
}

setInterval(() => {
  currentParams= step(currentParams.v , currentParams.theta);
}, 1);
```

- Use literal object as data structure to gather both `v` and `Θ` (theta).

  ↪ {v: `<initialValue>`, 'Θ' : `<initialValue>`}
- in the setInterval , the input of `step` will be that literal object and the output should be in the same structure to be assigned again .